# How can I remove a Button in its own onClick method?

Tags: android, android-button

I want to remove a Button in his own onClick method after it's clicked. I tried it with the normal way:
*layout.removeView(save);*
But the button will not be removed and I get no error. If I want to add the Button I get an error because the button already excists.

I think it isn't working because I trie to remove the button during his OnClickHandler is active. So my Question is how can I remove the button after he is clicked?

Comment: I would try hiding/showing it instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the complete, fully tested solution:

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

You can also completely remove the view from the layout like this (also tested):

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            parentView.removeView(view);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set its state with `button.setVisibility(Visibility.GONE)`

Comment: it doesn't work for me, the button isn't going to be invisible

Answer (score 0):

How about just hide it? e.g. in your button onclick handler you can do something like:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```